# 16V8 PLD alternatives for fast clock-to-data turnaround time

Tags: programmable-logic

Context:  I'm prototyping an MIPI I3C Basic slave device implemented on a PSOC5LP.   (I3C is similar to I2C, but is spec'd to run at up to 12.9 MHz.)  Due to a speed limitation of the PSOC, I'm considering using external programmable logic (e.g. a 16V8) to implement one small part of the design.   I'm looking for a more modern alternative to the 16V8 series parts.

The programmable logic on the PSOC can handle most of the timing requirements, but there is one spec'd clock-to-data timing that's hard to hit on the PSOC.   The I3C spec calls this **t<sub>SCO</sub>**, see figure below.

[image: Figure showing tSCO measurement]

For optimal operation, the [I3C Basic spec](https://resources.mipi.org/mipi-i3c-basic-v1-download) says **<sub>SCOmax</sub>** is 12nS, but [the best I'm likely to get out of the PSOC is > 23 ns](https://community.cypress.com/t5/PSoC-5-3-1-MCU/Clock-to-output-timing-achievable-w-PSOC5LP-UDB/m-p/228207).   Reading up on available parts, it seems that at least some variants of the basic 16V8 PLD can achieve clock-to-output time of 10ns.  That would do the trick, but it seems that in general 16V8s, and the like, are typically programmed out-of-circuit and require a CPLD programmer with specialized programming voltages and waveforms.

**Question:** Are there are alternative CPLD parts that can be programmed in-circuit, without programming voltages > 5V?

I'm thinking that a small FPGA might do, but it seems like overkill.

Note: the way **<sub>SCOmax</sub>** is defined, it doesn't include rise/fall times on the bus, but minimizing it gives the most headroom for the rise-time problems of bus capacitance.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me but I am very confused by your question.  You range from 16V8 to CPLD to PSoC to FPGA without really explaining what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks @jwh20, I've updated the first paragraph to help explain.  In short, the PSOC is a fixed choice, it may be augmented with a 16V8 (or FPGA) to meet a timing spec.

Comment: _"it seems that in general 16V8s, and the like, are typically programmed out-of-circuit and require a CPLD programmer with specialized programming voltages and waveforms." - https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/current-inexpensive-programmer-for-22v10_s-16v8_s/

Comment: https://nz.element14.com/xilinx/xc9536xl-5vqg44c/cpld-flash-5ns-178-6mhz-vqfp-44/dp/2907295?st=cpld

Comment: Thanks @BruceAbbot, I learned a lot reviewing the xilinx datasheet.   I guess JTAG programming was what I was really looking for.   The xilinx part still seems like overkill, but I'm closer to knowing what I want.

Comment: [iCE40 UltraLight](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/lattice-semiconductor-corporation/ICE40UL640-SWG16ITR/5130903) seems like it's even closer.   Packages as small as 10 I/Os, programmable with SPI.   Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Looks to be fast enough. So long as you don't mind programming it every time on startup and don't need higher than 3.3V logic it should do the job. 640 LUTs ought to be enough for anybody!

Comment: Yes, thanks @BruceAbbot.   3.3 V is no problem for this; I3C doesn't support 5 V.  But it will require an additional 2V2 rail for the ICE40 core.  I'm a bit concerned about prototyping with the WLCSO package, but this is a low-risk situation where the high speed is only an optimization.

Comment: _"I3C doesn't support 5 V"_ - Interesting. I only glanced at the spec, but ISTR it saying that it was compatible with legacy I2C devices. Not 5V ones then? _"this is a low-risk situation where the high speed is only an optimization"_ - then perhaps you are over-thinking it. I bet SDA doesn't have to change that quickly at lower speeds, and the PSOC might be fine by itself.

Comment: I3C is a MIPI spec, driven mostly by cell-phone interests; I think that's why 5V didn't enter into their standard.   The interesting thing is that they have published some materials about running 1V logic on high capacitance/long buses.  The I2C Basic spec defaults to Single Data Rate (SDR) where the nominal clock rate is 12.5 MHz.   A master can choose to go slower, but an I3C slave should be able to support SDR rate, or operate in I2C legacy mode (where everything is driven with open-drain signaling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not convinced that you really need programmable logic. The PSoC can update its data output *ahead of time* at the rising edge of the SCL, and use something fast to present that output on time to SDA when SCL falls. A tristate output D F-F, like 74LVC1G374 will do just that, with a propagation delay of 6ns max with 50pF load at 3.3V across temperature. Since the F-F needs to update on a falling clock edge, its clock input needs to be SCL inverted with e.g. 74LVC1G04, adding 3.3ns delay. You got 2ns to spare :)

If you want to drive larger capacitive loads, parallel a couple of those F-Fs. The inputs have 3pF typical input capacitance, so the maximum number of them in parallel depends on the allowed SCK unit load you can present.

You could probably make something a bit faster with discrete gold-doped switching transistors designed to stay fast even if driven into "saturation", but nobody makes those anymore, I don't think - and it'd be a power hog.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Kuba.   I was looking for a component like that. When I looked at 74HC374,  I concluded that octal FF was more than I wanted.   Thanks for pointing this comes in a tiny single-gate package, I had never before encountered "1G" parts.  I've learned something new.